# Function "artisan" is not defined in laravel 5.0.35

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

Why is that the -php artisan command in composer is not working on laravel5? I don't have any idea with this. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Here is the error in composer:

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "artisan" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public/
```